# Probability of complex eigenvalues

Tags: pr.probability, computer-science, estimation-theory

I find this is the best site to post this question, even though I considered [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

It is a Monte Carlo experiment over the set of 10.000 n×n matrices.
If a single matrix eigenvalue is complex then python numpy package will return all the eigenvalues as `numpy.complex128` type, else it will return all eigenvalues as `numpy.float64` type.

Here is the algorithm:

```
# Monte carlo experiment in numpy

import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

e=10000 # examples
# n - matrix rank
for n in range(1,10):
    cc=0 # complex counter
    for i in range (e):
        m=np.random.randn(n,n)#  m=np.random.random((n,n))        
        w, _ = LA.eig(m)        
        if (type(w[0]).__name__ == "complex128"):        
            cc+=1    
    print(f'matrix:{n}x{n}, total cases: {e}, complex cases: {cc}, ratio: {cc/e}')
```

The output of this algorithm is as follows:

```
matrix:1x1, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 0, ratio: 0.0
matrix:2x2, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 2851, ratio: 0.2851
matrix:3x3, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 6481, ratio: 0.6481
matrix:4x4, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 8782, ratio: 0.8782
matrix:5x5, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 9674, ratio: 0.9674
matrix:6x6, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 9944, ratio: 0.9944
matrix:7x7, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 9998, ratio: 0.9998
matrix:8x8, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 9999, ratio: 0.9999
matrix:9x9, total cases: 10000, complex cases: 10000, ratio: 1.0
```

It is very easy to understand the 1x1 case, since we take values from floating point numbers (set $\mathbb Q$) the eigenvalue will be the number itself (also in $\mathbb Q$).

For the case 2x2 and later, we may get complex eigenvalues ($\mathbb Z$).

I am counting the complex cases (where at least one eigenvalue is complex) and providing the ratio.

I would like to get some thoughts about this ratio possible the formula how to calculate one analytically.

---

My thought is that the ratio is not dependent on floating point arithmetic.
I used the normal distribution $\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, but one may test also the uniform distribution I commented.

Comment: To get a first guess of the functional dependence of the ration with respect to $n$: I would try first if f.i. this may be a logistic function. You can estimate the parameters of this function with programs as R or the python module pandas.

Comment: You may be interested in the paper "How Many Eigenvalues of a Random Matrix are Real?" by Alan Edelman, Eric Kostlan and Michael Shub

Comment: The fraction of eigenvalues that are strictly real decreases as $1/\sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The probability that a $n\times n$ real matrix (with elements that are independent random  variables with standard normal distributions) has only real eigenvalues is given by
$$ 2^{-n(n-1)/4}$$

Reference: A. Edelman, The Probability that a Random Real Gaussian Matrix has $k$ Real Eigenvalues, Related Distributions, and the Circular Law. Journal of  Multivariate Analysis 60, 203-232 (1997).

Comment: $1-2^{- \frac{n(n-1)}{4}}$ fits nice to what I got with MC. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any simple heuristic that would explain why it's asymptotically an exponential in $n^c$, with $c=2$? If the probabilities were independent for the $n$ eigenvalues, we'd expect $c=1$. If every matrix element had some probability of perturbing each eigenvalue off the real line, then maybe we'd imagine $c=3$. Maybe it's like random collisions between one eigenvalue and another, where being too close causes a repulsion that forces them off the real line? That would seem to make sense of the $c=2$.

Comment: @Ben Crowell There are $n^2$ independent random variables involved, namely the entries of the matrix... for this reason, the rate $n^2$ is typical of large deviations for the empirical measure of eigenvalues of random matrices.